# Incorrect table of content when using SVMULT (references appear twice per chapter)

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, sv-classes

I am working on a book using the Springer `SVMULT` template.  But there is a problem with the table of content. Here is the minimum working example:

**EDITOR.tex**

```
\documentclass{svmult}     
\begin{document}   
\tableofcontents  
\include{CHAPTER1}   
\end{document}
```

**CHAPTER1.tex**

```
\title*{The title}
\section{Introduction}
This is a citation \cite{name}.
\begin{thebibliography}{5}
\bibitem{name} An entry
\end{thebibliography}
```

**Output:**

[image]

As seen in Page 1, 'References' appears twice in the table of content, which is incorrect.

How can I fix this problem? I know that I could edit the .toc file. But it does not seems like a good solution, as it would be regenerated every time that I compile the book.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I downloaded the `svmult` class from [Springer’s website](https://www.springer.com/us/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636) and everything works fine. You may want to add the source of *your* `svmult` (where you find it).

Comment: Ok, i see, I will check it and update after.  Maybe this is the cause of the problem!  By the way thanks a lot for your answer to my other question yesterday.

Comment: I have downloaded the "SVMULT" class again but from Springer  (https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636 )  and it works now. This has solved the problem!  I think I must have had an old or corrupted version of SVMULT...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved with an update of the software (see comment).

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my question as it is solved. The problem was that the "SVMULT" class was outdated or corrupted. As suggested by "Ruixi Zhang" in the comments of this question, I have downloaded the class again but from the official Springer website and this has solved the problem.