# Again: Incorrect table of contents when using svmult.cls: References appear twice

Tags: cross-referencing, sv-classes

The original question has been marked closed, but it bytes me today.
Original question: [Incorrect table of content when using SVMULT (references appear twice per chapter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446149/incorrect-table-of-content-when-using-svmult-references-appear-twice-per-chapte)

I have downloaded the templates again from the indicated pages, the version is
% SVMULT DOCUMENT CLASS -- version 5.5 (23-Nov-18) (1st line)
resp.
\ProvidesClass{svmult}[2018/01/11 v5.5
(The dates differ).

The references entry appears twice.
This package also has some strange other "features": When using he subequations environment, the \label command introduces some extra space, such that the distance between text and an aligned formula becomes too large. There are also some strange error messages when using the \label inside a figure caption.

Comment: I was having the same issue with version 5.10 (12-June-23). I'm happy to report that egreg's solution still works!
@AloisSteindl: I didn't diff the versions. I can report that in the new version there are plenty of uses of \addcontentsline. Previously, a different user had an issue with a corrupted file: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446149/incorrect-table-of-content-when-using-svmult-references-appear-twice-per-chapte?newreg=a0a401846f6949a6974444659d35e776 Cheers,
Juergen

Answer (score 2):

For very strange reasons, the class adds twice the “References” entry in the TOC, in two different ways. Fix: remove one of them.

```
\documentclass{svmult}

% fix the double printing of references in the TOC
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\bibsection}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}}{}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\title*{The title}
\section{Introduction}
This is a citation \cite{name}.

\begin{thebibliography}{5}
\bibitem{name} An entry
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Version just downloaded from Springer:

```
% SVMULT DOCUMENT CLASS -- version 5.5 (23-Nov-18)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I diffed the file with the older version and found an instance of \addcontentsline. After commenting that out and sending the file to the issue editor, the second references entry was gone.
I am wondering that such a feature was not observed before, this version of svmult is 2 years old.

Comment: @AloisSteindl That's not the only flaw in the Springer classes, I'm afraid.